# How to line up buttons on Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using rows to layout my Tkinter program.
I usually use pack so my buttons would automatically place itself and not over lap, using rows, my buttons are overlapping, and I have to align them by changing their padx value. I was wondering if there was an easier way to do this.

```
from sys import argv
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageFilter
import random

script, infile = argv

class MyApp(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.wm_title("ImagePro")

        # Original
        original = Image.open(infile)
        (w, h) = (original.size[0], original.size[1])
        tkpi = ImageTk.PhotoImage(original)
        label = Label(self.root, image=tkpi)
        label.grid(row =0, column=0, padx=5,pady=5)

        img = original.copy().convert("L")
        tkpi2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        label = Label(self.root, image=tkpi2)
        label.grid(row =0, column=1, padx=5,pady=5)

        Label(self.root, text = "Original").grid(row=1, column=0)
        Label(self.root, text = "Modified").grid(row=1, column=1)
        Button(self.root, text = "Brighten").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
        Button(self.root, text = "Darken").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W, padx=60)
        Button(self.root, text = "Warm").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W, padx=112)
        Button(self.root, text = "Cool").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W, padx=158)

        self.root.mainloop()


MyApp()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do this you need to start using frames. A frame acts as a container for widgets. Add all the buttons to a frame, then add that frame to the root container.

```
class MyApp(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.wm_title("ImagePro")

        #Original
        original = Image.open(infile)
        (w, h) = (original.size[0], original.size[1])
        tkpi = ImageTk.PhotoImage(original)
        label = Label(self.root, image=tkpi)
        label.grid(row =0, column=0, padx=5,pady=5)

        img = original.copy().convert("L")
        tkpi2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        label = Label(self.root, image=tkpi2)
        label.grid(row =0, column=1, padx=5,pady=5)

        Label(self.root, text = "Original").grid(row=1, column=0)
        Label(self.root, text = "Modified").grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.buttonframe = Frame(self.root)
        self.buttonframe.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2)        
        Button(self.buttonframe, text = "Brighten").grid(row=0, column=0)
        Button(self.buttonframe, text = "Darken").grid(row=0, column=1)
        Button(self.buttonframe, text = "Warm").grid(row=0, column=2)
        Button(self.buttonframe, text = "Cool").grid(row=0, column=3)

        self.root.mainloop()
```

Each button goes in its own column within the frame, and the frame goes at the bottom of the main container.

Comment: A benefit of using `grid` is to avoid those intermediate extra-frames.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the same `row,column` couple for several widgets, they will appear in the same cell of the grid. Thus something like this should do the trick.

```
Button(self.root, text = "Brighten").grid(row=2, column=0)
Button(self.root, text = "Darken").grid(row=2, column=1)
Button(self.root, text = "Warm").grid(row=2, column=2)
Button(self.root, text = "Cool").grid(row=2, column=3)
```

You will find detailed information on this documentation of `grid` geometry manager http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm

Comment: That certainly works, but the top row has large images in it. If the buttons are placed in the same columns as the images they will be unevenly spread out. At least one extra frame should be used for this.

Comment: The usual answer to this is to span large widget over several column/rows.